# how to import variable record length csv file powershell

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a text file that is ';' separated. There is no header. And the "columns" are not the same. it looks like this

```
"TH01";"201";"1";"KA";"1";"1";"14.07.2015";
"TH02";"000800";"1";"Verkkomyynti";"Verkkomyynti";"Rudus Oy";"PL 49";"00441";"HELSINKI";"";"";
"TH03";"000800";"XXX";"RUSKATIE 25";"10104307 JORMA KOSKINEN";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"36KM";
```

I tried to import this file using

```
$filecvs = import-Csv -Path "C:\test.txt" -Delimiter ';' 
foreach($row in $filecvs)
{  
   $field1 = $row.field1  
   $field2 = $row.field2   
   Echo "$field1, $field2" 
}
```

And I got an error
import-Csv : The member "1" is already present.

```
At line:1 char:12
+ $filecvs = import-Csv -Path "C:\test.txt...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Csv], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AlreadyPresentPSMemberInfoInternalCollectionAdd,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

My objective is to loop through the file and get the value of certain fields and add them up. If I cannot use import-csv then what is the best way to work around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example it appears that each line has different numbers of fields. For example, the first line has 8 fields, and the second has 12. Are the fields in line 1 the same fields as the first 8 shown for line 2? Are the fields in line 2 the same as the first 12 (of 14) in line 3? Could we simply add blank fields to the ends of those lines and have everything line up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import-CSV expects the first line to be a header line, defining the name for the fields. It's throwing the error "the member '1' is already present" because you have the value '1' twice in your first line, and it can't name two properties (fields) the same name.

You can just add the -Header parameter to Import-Csv to cause it to parse all data in the csv file as data.

Example:

```
$filecvs = import-Csv -Path "C:\test.txt" -Delimiter ';' -Header Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5...
```

Comment: Thank you jbsmith. Very helpful. Appreciated:)